# Command line MySQL query export output to file not working in Windows

Tags: mysql, sql, windows

Version of `mysql` is `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.53, for Win64 (AMD64)`

After running below commands, the output still goes to `stdout`

```
mysql -uroot -proot DBinstance

select * from tablename\G INTO OUTFILE 'c:\users\12345\Downloads\some_non_existingfile'
```

---

What is the problem with above command?

**Edit:**

I get below error after re-correcting the `select` query:

`ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv opti
on so it cannot execute this statement`

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| secure_file_priv | NULL  |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Currently `G:\..\mysql> dir` have folders `bin`, `data`, `lib`, `scripts` & `tmp`.

Comment: Does MySQL have the permissions to write at that location?  Also, as you seem to know, the file cannot already exist.

Comment: i have amended my answer to show how to alter the ecure_file_priv setting

Answer (score 1):

remove the \G flag.

```
select * from tablename INTO OUTFILE 'c:\users\12345\Downloads\some_non_existingfile'
```

you also need to make sure that
The MySQL server is not running with the --secure-file-priv option

to allow for writing output to a folder
add or amend your mysql config file (my.ini) by adding/amending the following line.

```
secure-file-priv = ""
```

or

```
secure-file-priv = "FOLDER-PATH-OF-YOUR-CHOICE"
```

then restart the mysql server using

```
net stop mysql
net start mysql
```

little info about the setting

If empty, the variable has no effect.

If set to the name of a directory, the server limits import and export operations to work only with files in that directory. The directory must exist; the server will not create it.

If set to NULL, the server disables import and export operations. This value is permitted as of MySQL 5.7.6.

Comment: How to verify secure file priv option?

Comment: @overexchange SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";

Comment: @overexchange setting most likely in your my.ini file.

Comment: Can I set and unset this option to export the query output? Db is in production...

Comment: no, i believe it is a startup setting only. if you run SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv"; you can see what folder you can output too, maybe you have access to the folder?

Comment: `>mysql -V` gives `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.53, for Win64 (AMD64)`. Does this version allow to set this variable?

Comment: setting the value to NULL was only permitted version 5.7.6 onwards, Seems you the setting as NULL and thats what your issue is, Try changing the setting to "" (empty string) restart the MySQL service and see what happens. The Official documentation is here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_secure-file-priv

Comment: Currently `c:\..\mysql> dir` have folders `bin`, `data`, `lib`, `scripts` & `tmp`. Where should I create this file `my.ini`?

Comment: you wil already have an my.ini file, is it normally located C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server x.x\my.ini or C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server x.x\my.ini

Comment: Neither I see `ProgramData` folder nor I see `MySQL Server x.x` in `MySQL`. `*.cnf` files are in `..\mysql` folder

Comment: ProgramData is hidden by default , typing C:\ProgramData\ into the filebrowser address bar and hit enter,  x.x just donates the version of your mysql , could be 5,6 5,7 etc

Comment: You are right... `ProgramData` is hidden by default... I do not see mysql* folder in `c:\ProgramData`

Comment: I guess, where is your my.ini file is a whole other question.