# How to locate my.ini file?

Tags: mysql, sql

Further to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51686089/3317808),

Neither am unable to locate `my.ini` file nor able to decide the location to create `my.ini` file.

`ProgramData` is hidden by default... I do not see mysql* folder in `c:\ProgramData`

`G:\business_app_folder\mysql> dir` have folders `bin`, `data`, `lib`, `scripts`, `share` & `tmp`.

Mysql folder does not exist in `ProgramFiles`

---

How to decide the location of `my.ini` file?

Comment: Windows Explorer. Click on *This PC* (or *My Computer*, if you're using an older version) and enter *my.ini* in the search box in the upper right, then click the *Search* button (the little magnifying glass) on the right side of the search box. Sit back and wait for the search to find it..

Comment: MySQL folder in windows usually goes in "program files" folder, not "programdata"

Comment: After your edit, the answer is (again) WIndows Explorer's search functionality. Search for `mysql` to locate your MySQL installation folder.

Comment: @KenWhite what subfolders does mysql installation folder consist of? To recognise that this is installation folder..

Comment: Are you getting so many results that they're confusing to you? You shouldn't.

Comment: @KenWhite I see mysql folder in G: drive, which is updated in query..

Comment: The poster who answered your linked question already told you where the file should be located, in the comment discussion you had below that answer. What more do you expect us to tell you here? If you've looked in that location yourself, and you've used Windows Explorer to search your entire computer for that file and it didn't find it, it's apparently not there.

Comment: @KenWhite answer in linked question says mysql should be in programdata folder, which isn't in my case..

Comment: Again, Windows Explorer search looks at your entire computer. Did you search the G: drive? I gave you specific instructions how to do the search, step by step. Did you follow them? If your MySQL installation is not where it's supposed to be, you decided to install it somewhere else when you ran the installer. We don't know what you did. We can't search your computer for you.

Comment: @KenWhite I searched using windows explorer, i could not find...

Comment: Please Google *MySQL documentation*. Find the documentation for the version of MySQL you're using, and then find the topic *Creating an option file* (in MySQL 8.0, it's in section [2.3.5.2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-create-option-file.html). Adjust the location for the file to the proper one matching your MySQL installation (apparently your G: drive).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache server, it is in 
...\mysql\bin

Inside bin folder.

Comment: I voted this answer.. but you can delete this answer... Because am not using Apache server.. Things are working now...